# How do I rabbit hop and micro snipe?

Tags: counter-strike

HI all. I am new to counter strike and this site. I was recently in a competition. I found many players use new moves. I'd like to know how to do the rabbit hop and how to micro snipe. Thank you.

Comment: Usually it's called "bunny hopping", and I'm unfamiliar with "micro sniping" and can't find anything on it

Comment: I played CS obsessively for many years, and was even in a professional clan for a while, but I've never heard of "micro sniping."  Is that a new term in CS:S?

Answer (score 7):

With respect to *bunny hopping*, in the old GoldSrc games (Counter-Strike, TFC, HLDM) you could gain significant speed when jumping and strafing (moving sideways, e.g. with <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd>)  Begin by moving forward and jumping.  While in mid-air, stop holding forward (<kbd>W</kbd>), and only strafe with either A or D.  When you hit the ground, **immediately** jump.  You continue to move faster and faster without ever hitting forward (<kbd>W</kbd>), but only if your jump timing is nailed down and you strafe only.  Some people will bind `+jump` to `mwheelup` and/or `mwheeldown` and just roll the wheel to try to hit the timing.

As mentioned, I'm unfamiliar with "micro sniping", but a common tactic when using scoped rifles is to quick-switch weapons to avoid spending any significant time scoped.  To do so,  line up a shot with a rifle, unscoped, then quickly `mouse2` to scope, `mouse1` to fire, then <kbd>2</kbd> to switch to your sidearm as fast as possible.  Done well, the switch is virtually instant and you can begin firing rounds from your pistol almost immediately.  This allows you to finish off your target(s) if need be, without wasting time scoping or waiting on the delay to fire your rifle again.

Comment: I've never heard the term micro snipe either and I've been playing CS since 1.5.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe 'micro-sniping' = 'quick-scoping'!
It can be done by pressing the scope and shoot button almost together. It results in an almost unscope shoot but eliminating the uncertainty of an unscoped awp shot.
I think its called micro because the scope time period is very small